# Error 20 Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BIND' symbol in VS 2005 when recompilation

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

How to solve this error.Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BIND' symbol in VS 2005 when recompilation.Upon every time I compiles my code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).